# How to isolate specific hyperlinks using simple html dom php

Tags: php, dom

How to isolate specific hyperlinks from a website(using simple html dom php). for example below script were i want only the link which have the bolded path with http://www.website.com/**release**/...

```
<a class="blue" href="/releases/2012.htm">release of ---</a>
<a class="blue" href="/releases/1/2012.htm">release of ---</a>
```

and links which has  a subdomain (*news*) in it

```
 <a class="blue" href="http://news.website.com/one/1">release of ---</a>
```

and also is there any way to isolate a specific link from a website and go inside that specific link and fetch its title and description

Comment: Hi there. You can user jquery for this king of operation. what you can do is fist fetch all the <a> tag element and the traverse a loop that fetch all href. Once you have href array match each one with the regular expression or use your own way to choose specific link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd just iterate over all of the links, checking to see if each one matches your conditions, and if so, grab the data you want from it.

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
    if(substr($link->href, 0, 10) == "/releases/") {
        // do stuff with a releases link
    }

    // and so on
}
```

Comment: what is this means (substr($link->href, 0, 10)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all links that can be a potential match, then check whether their `href` matches your criteria. You can do this check by using [basic string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) or [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) if the criteria are too advanced for basic matches.

Comment: Though your answers are usually great, they're not always clear for beginners. Providing a code example with some comments can greatly enchance the clarity of your answer. Also, it's not common on Stack Overflow to simply paste a link to a page containing the answer, as those online sources can go offline.